# kendoui splitter error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

I have a kendo splitter in my single paged application. In a certain scenario I want to remove and clear the contents of the container which holds the splitter.
But on IE after I clear the container and re-size the browser window, an error appears:

`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'offsetHeight': object is null or undefined`

I clear the contents by `$('#container').html('')`.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H5Ef6/2/

Comment: On which version of IE? I was not able to reproduce it on IE9 with mode IE9 / IE8 and IE7...

Comment: IE 9, To reproduce: open the console, click the clear button, resize the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [official documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/splitter), they propose to `destroy` the splitter. But with the kendo ui library that you have, this method does not exists. But what it mainly does is to remove the `resize` binding on this splitter.

Thus, when you clear your container, you should unbind this event like this :

```
$("#vertical").data("kendoSplitter").unbind("resize");
```

(see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLcfE/1/)).

Comment: you can destroy any kendo widget by just removing the DOM element it is bound to. all data relevant to widget initialization is stored with the element.

Comment: I agree, but the resize binding remains (at least in IE) even when the DOM element is removed.

Comment: probably worth filing a bug report to telerik ;)

Comment: It seems to be known by the Telerik team since they have explicitely instanciated a destroy method indicated in their official documentation (see my previous link)... But I agree that it looks like a bug that should be removed!!! :-)